# How can I distinguish what type of JSON API response this is?

Tags: xml, json, api, jsonp

I am new to JSON and XML. When doing a POST or GET request to an API, how can I tell the type of response given? For example, is it JSON or RAW or application? Can someone tell me what kind of response this is from a web API? Why are there quotes around every key and property?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
{
  "audioChannels": "5.1",
  "audioCodec": "DolbyDigital",
  "container": "mkv",
  "episodeNumber": 3,
  "format": "WEBRip",
  "mimetype": "video/x-matroska",
  "releaseGroup": "NTb",
  "screenSize": "1080p",
  "season": 2,
  "series": "House of Cards",
  "title": "NF",
  "type": "episode",
  "videoCodec": "h264",
  "year": 2013
}
```

Is this JSON? JSONP? XML? What is this?

Comment: It looks like the HTTP status followed by some JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a plain JSON response (with some HTTP response information prepended).

Answer (score 0):

This is an API response from GuessIt. GuessIt itself is a python library that tries to extract as much information as possible from a filename.

- http://guessit.readthedocs.org/
- https://github.com/wackou/guessit

### Web Service API

The guessit.io server also provides a free webservice that allows you to perform filename detection, even you don’t have python installed (eg: you need to use it from an Android app, or NodeJS, etc.).

You can look at the documentation for the web API here:

- http://api.guessit.io/